# importing data from sql to csv every hour

Tags: javascript, sql, csv, breadcrumbs

i would like to create a interval which every hour import data from sql to csv file

i don't know if to use cron or website with JavaScript interval

imalso worried about the security issue.

would love to hear your elegant responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't sound like you need javascript, instead take a look at [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)